# 'method' object is not subscriptable error occurs

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am a student who is studying Janggo. I want to get all the value_code itself as a getlist, but it's not working. How can I get it on the getlist? I want to get a request.POST.getlist, but I don't know how to get it using form. How should I modify it? I would really appreciate your help.

**Error :**

```
TypeError at /join/join_create/1/
'method' object is not subscriptable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/join/join_create/1/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'method' object is not subscriptable
Exception Location: C:\zeronine_project (5)\join\views.py, line 37, in join_create
Python Executable:  D:\anaconda3\envs\vnv_zn\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\zeronine_project (5)',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\DLLs',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\lib',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn',
 'D:\\anaconda3\\envs\\vnv_zn\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 13 Aug 2021 02:21:20 +0900
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
D:\anaconda3\envs\vnv_zn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
D:\anaconda3\envs\vnv_zn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\zeronine_project (5)\join\views.py, line 37, in join_create
                    element.value_code = request.POST.getlist['value_code'] …
▶ Local vars
```

**views.py**

```
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ElementForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                element = Element()
                element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                element.value_code = request.POST.getlist['value_code']
                element.save()

            else:
                element = Element()
                element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                element.value_code = None
                element.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
 class ElementForm(forms.Form):
    value_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(error_messages={'required': "옵션을 선택하세요."}, label="옵션", queryset=Value.objects.all())
```

**html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'zeronine:join_create' id=product.product_code %}">
    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: -5px">
        <label for="optionSelect" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label"><b>옵션</b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left: -90px;">
                 <select type="text" class="form-control" name="value_code" id="optionSelect" value="{{ form.value_code }}">
                     <option value="none">옵션을 선택하세요.</option>
                        {% for option in option_object %}
                           {% if option.option_code.option_code.option_code == value.option_code %}
                               {%if option.product_code == product %}
                                   <optgroup label="{{option.name}}">
                        {% for value in value_object %}
                           {% if value.option_code.option_code == option.option_code %}
                               {%if value.product_code == product %}
                                     <option data-price="{{value.extra_cost}}"value="{{value.value_code}}" multiple='multiple'>{{value.name}} (+{{value.extra_cost}}원)</option>
                               {% endif %}
                           {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                               {% endif %}
                           {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                                 </optgroup>
                </select>
```

Comment: try this `request.POST.getlist('value_code[]')`

Comment: @boyenec The following error occurs: Cannot assign "[]": "Element.value_code" must be a "Value" instance.

Comment: You might  be add 'element.instance.value_code` in your views.py

Comment: @boyenec The same error still occurs. I changed the method and wrote it as follows, can you see if there is a problem with this?

Comment: @boyenec             for value_code in request.POST.getlist('value_code'):
                element = Element()
                element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                element.value_code = value_code
                element.save()

Comment: @boyenec I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
if request.method == "POST":
            form = ElementForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.instance.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                form.instance.value_code = request.POST.getlist['value_code']
                form.save()

            else:
                form.instance.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                form.instance.value_code = None
                form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage should be `.getlist('value_code')`. And since you get a list, you need to check which element is going to be used.

For example if you want the first item to be used:

```
value_codes = request.POST.getlist('value_code')
element.value_code = value_codes[0] if value_codes else None
```

But it all still depends on how you passed this in the request.